# Rails app deploy on openshift

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, openshift-online-2

I'm trying to deploy Rails application no openshift (rails-2.0 + postrgesql). I think automatic deploy on git push didn't execute  rake task db:setup and db:migrate, because I see

```
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist
```

in `~/logs/ruby.log`

My question is how can I run rake tasks manually? In what dir I suppose to be? Can I run Rails console on openshift?

Answer (score 1):

You should go to app directory:

```
cd ~/app-root/repo/
```

then you can run rake commands (e.g. rake db:migrate).
You can go to Rails console by running:

```
rails console
```